# Calling a function if any new tag is created in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to call a function in WordPress which is triggered by creating new post tag in WordPress.

May be the issue is with action call, at first i tried to use this `add_action( 'edit_tag_form', 'update_tags',10 ,2 );` but after reading i got to know WordPress has dismantled this action call.
then, 
I tried to achieve this via this, But it is not working.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

```
function update_tags($ID, $tags) {
$data = array("name" => $tags->name,"slug" => $tags->slug); 

$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   

$ch = curl_init('ANY API');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);
}
add_action( 'post_tag_edit_form', 'update_tags',10 ,2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you should be able to use the newer hook:

```
{$taxonomy}_add_form
```

Check out the reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/taxonomy_add_form/

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, and it worked fine 
add_action( 'post_tag_add_form', 'update_tags',10 ,2 );
can you tell me hou would ill be able to get $tags->name and $tags->slug 
actually its also not getting tag crated tag name and tag slug

Comment: You should be able to get that with the get_the_tags() function. [https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags)